# Configure User Registration with IdentityServer3?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I am very new to Authentication and Authorization. So I have some questions ask from the community.This is what have I done so far.I search on how to do Authentication and Authorization I see the IdentityServer3 and I configure with my project. In my project I have separate DB to IDServer and One to project. I search that is there a way to configure user registration with identityserver3. Is that possible ??
I couldn't found a clue to do that then I configure ASP.NET Identity with my project that explain in [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.0.0-beta1) .
These are my Questions.

1. Is there a possible way to user registration using IdentityServer3 or Is that only do manage logins,Authentication and Authorization??
2. What is the best way to keep the user data.[user name , email , password].
   Currently I keep users data in my project. Do I need to keep user data in IDServer.

   3. In ASP.NET Identity there is a roles and is that identical to Claims ??

How can I add user registration form to my project with configuring IdentityServer3.
If there is a better way to user registration can someone point me out ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Identity Server 3 is only authentication. User registration, password resets, etc. should be handled by a separate application which Identity Server could link off to.
2. You should store your identity data in any user store (e.g. ASP.NET Identity or Membership Reboot). This should be in a database. Identity Server can then use this user store to authenticate users and generate their claims.
3. The Roles table in ASP.NET Identity is just an abstraction of the role claim. So yes, it is just another claim.

The ASP.NET Identity libraries offer some good APIs for user registration. I would recommend creating an application that exposes that and have Identity Server link off to it. Identity Server does not do this out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I found your blog and read how can I use ASP.NET Identity with IdentityServer3. I found a example in your blog and I think I have a idea what should I do.Thank you for help.